# Using google maps using coordinates

Tags: javascript, html

currently i am on a web project in that i want to display the location in google maps using the coordinates i.e., longitude and latitude. I know we can use code some thing like follows to display the static map

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?    
    center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap
    &markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,
    -74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
    &markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false" />
```

But i didn't get how to manage the parameter and where to specify the coordinates.. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better have a look at the [**Google Static Map API documentation**](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

This page says that you should use the parameter `center`:

> **Location Parameters**:
>
> - center (required if markers not present) defines
>     the center of the map, equidistant from all edges of the map. This
>     parameter takes a location as either a comma-separated
>     {latitude,longitude} pair (e.g. "40.714728,-73.998672") or a string
>     address (e.g. "city hall, new york, ny") identifying a unique location
>     on the face of the earth. For more information, see Locations below.

**Example**

Here is the URL, you could use:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false

Comment: shall i use the longitude and latitude values and still get the appropriate google map ??

Comment: you can use either text or longitude / latitude depending on your needs. Both will work